# gradle resolutionStrategy not updating runtime

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

In my gradle build script, I forced 3.1.0 release libraries for spring framework. I see that this resolution strategy change is applied to compile, testCompile, testRuntime but not to runtime as visible from 'gradle dependencies' output.

```
allprojects {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if ( details.requested.group == 'org.springframework' ) { 
                    details.useVersion = '3.1.0.RELEASE'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

gradle dependencies output:

```
compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.1
+--- com.company.mod1:module1:2.21.2
```

`|    +---` org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.0.RC1 -> **3.1.0.RELEASE**

```
  |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.0.RELEASE
    |    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.0.RC1 -> 3.1.0.RELEASE
    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.1.0.RELEASE
    |    |    |    +--- aopalliance:uopalliance:1.0
    |    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.1.0.RELEASE


runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.1
+--- com.company.mod1:module1:2.21.2
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.0.RC1
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.0.0.RC1
|    |    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.0.RC1
|    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.0.0.RC1
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.0.RC1
|    |    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-asm:3.0.
```

As you can compile dependencies got over written with 3.1.0.RELEASE but runtime did not. As a result when I distribute a zip for my project jar, I see 3.0.0. version spring libraries.

Is this a problem with my override or resolution strategy does not impact runtime libs?
Do I need to include compile dependencies in distZip task? But this might create duplicate libs in the archive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

found out the cause. resolutionStrategy code method was at the bottom of the build script. Once I moved it above all sub projects related build code, it reflected runtime dependencies too.